# Django: Last template `{% if tag %}` on page being ignored. First `{% if tag %}` has nested tags

Tags: html, django, django-templates

In my SessionWizardViews `wizard_form.html` page I use template [{% if tags %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#if) to show different content to the user depending on the survey URL and which page of each survey they are on. This is two levels of nested `{% if tags %}`

At the bottom of the `wizard_form.html` page I have another top level if tag `{% if wizard.steps.current not in no_next_button %}` which I use to remove the Next button on pages 2, 8 and 25 as I replace it on those pages. `no_next_button` comes from a `context.update` in my views.py. When the condition is satisfied the Next button should not be visible at the bottom of the page.

**This solution works on my local machine however occasionally the Next button is not visible on the wrong page when I deploy it on the server.** I can find no pattern to when this happens and get no error!

I believe what is happening is the last template if tag is getting ignored, but I have no idea how or why that might be. Can anybody shed some light on the situation and tell me what might be going wrong?

I have reversed the logic used to display the Next button but still occasionally get the issue. Thanks

Django 1.6.2

**Edit**

A force refresh Shift + Cmd + R will fix the issue when it occurs. This might provide further insight to some.

**wizard_form.html**

```
{% if 'surveyone' in request.path %}    
    {% if wizard.steps.current in it_step_one %} 
            <div id="dialog-message" title="Instruction Task 1">
            ....
    {% endif %}

    {% if wizard.steps.current in steps %}            
            <div class="image_rating">      
            <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathone/" %}{{display_image}}" value="{{display_image}}" onload="updateInput(this)"/>                                                                                    
            </div>
            ....
   {% endif %}
{% endif %}



{% if 'surveytwo' in request.path %}    
    {% if wizard.steps.current in it_step_one %} 
            <div id="dialog-message" title="Instruction Task 1">
            ....
    {% endif %}

    {% if wizard.steps.current in steps %}            
            <div class="image_rating">      
            <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathtwo/" %}{{display_image}}" value="{{display_image}}" onload="updateInput(this)"/>                                                                                    
            </div>
            ....
   {% endif %}
{% endif %}

{% if 'surveythree' in request.path %}
    ....
```

The Next button if tag

```
{% if wizard.steps.current not in no_next_button %}  
        <input class="btn btn-default btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="{% trans "Next" %}"/>
{% endif %}
```

**views.py**

```
class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                             
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)                      
        step = int(self.steps.current)    

            ....
            .... 


            # Remember if you change these you have to change your JavaScript
            steps = ['10','11','12','14','15','16','19','20','21']              
            it_step_one = ['0']
            it_step_two = ['1']
            no_next_button = ['2', '8', '25']

            context.update({'steps' : steps,
                            'it_step_one' : it_step_one, 
                            'it_step_two' : it_step_two,
                            'no_next_button' : no_next_button,
                            })

        return context
```

Comment: Could it have to do with your javascript?

Comment: That is a possibility, maybe the JavaScript is stopping the browser from going back up to the top level of `{% if tags %}' and continuing on to find the last one on the page. Ill try test that now by moving the next button to the top.

Comment: It appears you are correct. moving the Next button segment to the top of the page means it renders each and every time. Some of my JavaScript is inline and some external. Would moving it all to external files solve this?

Comment: If you write your answer up as a solution I would be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed your comment in the code about needing to change the javascript if the values get changed.  Maybe there is something in your **javascript** that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it has something to do with `wizard.steps.current`. Since you didn't provide full source, there is no way to tell what is amiss. My suggestion is to print `self.steps.current` or show `{{wizard.steps.current}}` in your template to help debugging the problem.

Comment: I have been printing `self.steps.current` and showing `{{wizard.steps.current}}`, the correct values are being displayed each time. I am not really sure what other code might be useful in this case.